# Merge two servers together

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, localhost

I am using jQuery/Ajax to do some web-scraping and use the data on my website. The jQuery container is currently running using `python3 -m http.server 8989`, while the locally deployed website runs on `localhost:3000`.

I need to combine these two so that they can be deployed and displayed on the same website, but am not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should ask this question on [StackExchange ProWebmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions) instead of here.

Comment: Basically you put a webserver like nginx or Apache in front of them.